# End Remote Desktop Session and Standby

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, batch-file

I've setup remote access on my computer (Windows 7 Pro x64 via RDP). The [WOL] wake-on-lan function is already working so I can wake it up from sleeping. When I end a remote desktop session (`start-menu` -> `logout`) the computer just stays at the login screen and doesn't go back to sleep.

I'd like to have a batch file *(or really something)* which I can execute from my remote PC to `1.` end *(disconnect or logout)* the RDP session and `2.` put the PC to sleep *(it does NOT have to logout the user)*.

I tried setting up a windows task which puts the computer to sleep 30 seconds after a user logs out *(didn't work)*. I tried putting it to sleep using a batch file already but the session kept running, and I could not do anything and had to hard boot my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **End RemoteDesktop Session and Standby**
>
> create a batch file (or really something) which i can activate from my
>   remote-pc to end the session and put the pc to sleep (does not have to
>   log out the user)

---

Two example scripts below:

1. with a `LOGOFF`; and,
2. another with an RDP `DISCONNECT` (no logoff)

I wasn't sure if you wanted one or the other so I put both below which should work fine from Windows 7 from what I tested.

For the logoff script, I put some if logic to not logoff console, system, or rdp-tpc listening sessions since you're only interesting in RDP connected remote sessions.

For the disconnect script you will just disconnect the session that runs it as needed so no need for additional logic on this one ***(this is the one you probably need)***.

The assumption is you will run this as a saved batch script manually and if you decide to use the logoff script rather than the disconnect script, you will have permission to logoff all or any applicable sessions.

---

### BATCH SCRIPTS

*(This script will also wait 5 seconds after the disconnect of the current session and then put the PC to sleep.)*

**Batch Script Example (`DISCONNECT` all sessions)**

```
@ECHO OFF

::: Disconnected current RDP session
TSDISCON 

::: Pause 5seconds before going to sleep ensuring enough time 
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL

::: Put computer to sleep
%systemroot%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

GOTO EOF
```

---

*(This script will also wait 30 seconds after the logoff all the sessions and then put the PC to sleep.)*

**WARNING:** *This script will not be able to be run ad hoc by double clicking this batch file for the OP's needs specifically, but I kept this here as a bonus item in case anyone finds use with it otherwise. Since it will logoff the accounts before the sleep logic runs, that sleep logic will not work in that particular case. This would need to be run from Task Scheduler, `with Highest Privileges`, and `Run whether the user is logged on or not`—I supposed you could setup this way and NOT on a schedule and just kick off/run as needed from Task Scheduler too. (screen shot below)*

**Batch Script Example (`LOGOFF` all sessions)**

```
@ECHO OFF

FOR /F %%S IN (

    '"QUERY SESSION /SM"'

) DO (

IF NOT %%~S==0 IF NOT %%~S==1 IF NOT %%~S==65536 RWINSTA %%~S

)

::: Pause 5 seconds before going to sleep ensuring enough time 
PING -n 5 127.0.0.1 > NUL

::: Put computer to sleep
%systemroot%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState 0,1,0

GOTO EOF
```

**Screen Shot Scheduled Task Options**

[image]

---

### Further Research, Reading, and Sources

- [TSDISCON](http://ss64.com/nt/tsdiscon.html)
- [RWINSTA](http://ss64.com/nt/reset-session.html)
- [QUERY SESSION](http://ss64.com/nt/query-session.html)
- [SERVER FAULT
  RESOURCE](https://serverfault.com/questions/41499/scripting-how-to-disconnect-remote-desktop-sessions)

Comment: The second method did not work, since it terminates the script after the logoff (at least i think thats what happens). The first one however worked like a charm,thanks!

Comment: I also like the way you used ping to wait 5 seconds, never would have though of that :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: click a blank spot on the Desktop while in RDP session and press Alt+F4. You'll get the old "power" menu and from there you can force your computer to go to sleep and that will also disconnect your RDP of course.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks. But i am asking myself why the sleep option is there and not in the normal place.